# QTable Widget Column 0 (zero) not updating

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

Hi i Have a QTable widget in window.

The column data will be updating pragmatically.

Currently all are working fine but index 0 column is not refreshing on data update (if i click table widget or re-size window its updating). But other columns are responding fine.

I am posting a sample code snippet here at [PastBin](http://pastebin.com/F1WCaDSB).

In this snippet, when we click the buttons (A,B,C,D) they will update the count in Row 1 (Complex Shots) in there respective columns.

Like if we press Button A. It will increment count in cell (0,0) and update Total in cell (0,4)

Like if we press Button B. It will increment count in cell (0,1) and update Total in cell (0,4)

Like if we press Button C. It will increment count in cell (0,2) and update Total in cell (0,4)

Like if we press Button D. It will increment count in cell (0,3) and update Total in cell (0,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could overcome this issue by decreasing the size of the Column Header.
Exactly don't know the reason whether its a pyqt bug. But doing like this has solved our issue.